# I can detect whether its mobile or desktop but further i want to detect that which mobile browser is accessing URL?

Tags: browser, mediarecorder

I am working on mediarecorder so I stuck at detecting the mobile browser(for iphone also) so that I can open url forcefully in chrome

```
var URL = window.location.href;
var RedirectFlag = getUrlVars()["redirectflag"];
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    if(RedirectFlag=='1')
    {
        function();
    }    
    else
    {
    URL = URL.replace("http://123", "intent://123");
    URL = URL + "&redirectflag=1#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end";
    window.location.href = URL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: Are you sure *none* of these 100s (edit: *1000s*) of questions answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+mobile+browser

Comment: This all are about detecting mobile or desktop.I want to detect mobile browser i.e which app the user is using in mobile(chrome,safari,firefox).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction.

Comment: https://www.whatsmyua.info/ might help you and has links to existing libraries (I realise you're not specifically asking for a library, but sometimes easier than reinventing the wheel if it does what you want).

Comment: i am working on it i will inform you as I solve it and Thanks bro!!

Comment: all plugins are showing browser name as chromium in all app browsers of mobile.